In Angular how to segregate the part of reactive form in seperate ng-template (s) inside same component?
I want to use some part of the angular reactive form will come from an ng-template. Seperating in different component will work fine with ngViewProviders. But I want to achieve it via ng-template.
        <h1>Test Reactive Form</h1>
        <form [formGroup]="form">
          <ng-container
          [ngTemplateOutlet]="formArray"
          [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{formGroup:form, arrayName:test}"
          ></ng-container>
        </form> 
        {{form.value | json}}

        <ng-template #formArray let-formGroup="formGroup" let-arrayName="arrayName"  >
          
          <ng-container [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <div formArray="arrayName">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let t of arrayName.controls;let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
              {{formGroup.value | json}}
            <input type="text"/>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
      `,
    })
    export class App {
      name = 'Angular';
      form;
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          test: this.fb.array([]),
        });

        const test = this.fb.group({
          name: 'Test name',
        });
        this.test.push(test);
        const test_1 = this.fb.group({
          name: 'test name 2',
        });
        this.test.push(test_1);
      }

      get test(): FormArray {
        return this.form.get('test') as FormArray;
      }

Getting erro like
ERROR
Error: Cannot find control with name: '0'
Stackbitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9jmcfq?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Without explicitly use of formGroup inside ng-template gives another error, like formArray can't be used without formGroup

the attributes formGroupName, formGroup, formArray and formArrayName must have a proper HTML element defined, removed all ng-container and replaced with div.
For defining form array you should use formArrayName, the name should match the label test that you defined inside the formGroup({...}).
The input inside the for loop should have formControlName="name" added.
  <ng-template #formArray let-formGroup="formGroup" let-arrayName="arrayName"  >
    <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <div formArrayName="test">
        <div *ngFor="let t of arrayName.controls;let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

Full Code:
import 'zone.js';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
  <h1>Test Reactive Form</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="formArray"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{formGroup:form, arrayName:test}"
    ></ng-container>
  </form> 
  {{form.value | json}}

  <ng-template #formArray let-formGroup="formGroup" let-arrayName="arrayName"  >
    <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <div formArrayName="test">
        <div *ngFor="let t of arrayName.controls;let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
          <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
          `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  form;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      test: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    const test = this.fb.group({
      name: 'Abhisek',
    });
    this.test.push(test);
    const test_1 = this.fb.group({
      name: 'Abhisek2',
    });
    this.test.push(test_1);
  }

  get test(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('test') as FormArray;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, it worked now. But do we have any option to skip the two time formGroup
once from where the ng-template is being loaded and another inside the template

@AbhisekMalakar that is the reference to which form the content in the template belongs to, it has to be there
